TikZ rotate coordinate axes
I generated the following figure:

My question is: How can I rotate all three coordinate axes such that the y-axis is tangent to the curve at the origin?
CODE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \coordinate (D) at (0,0);
    \draw (D) [<-,>=stealth']  arc[start angle=90, end angle=150, radius=7 ] coordinate [pos=0.5] (O);
    \filldraw[black] (O) circle (2pt) node [left] {Origin};
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(135:2);
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(45:2);
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(315:2);
    \draw ([shift=(45:.4)] O) arc (45:135:.4);
    \filldraw ([shift=(90:.2)] O) circle (.4pt);
    \node at (-5.05,0.58) {z};
    \node at (-1.95,0.59) {y};
    \node at (-1.95,-2.5) {x};
    % added
    \coordinate (P) at ($(O) + (45:2)$); % (45:2) is perpendicular to the x and z axes
    \begin{scope}[shift=(P)]
    \draw[smooth,variable=\Vt,domain=180:275,-stealth'] plot ({2*cos(\Vt)},{2*sin(\Vt)});
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


@ s28 I added the right angle which I forgot, with the angles-library,

(These axis directions z parallel to x is a bit strange, but your picture.) 
So draw your coordinate-system in a different way, by using the middle-point (M, which I hide and overlay here) of the (blue) circle-arc:
Your arc:
\coordinate[label=D] (D) at (0,0);
\draw[blue, <-](D) arc[start angle=90, end angle=150, radius=7] coordinate [pos=0.5] (O);  

so:
\coordinate[overlay](M) at ($(D)-(0,7)$);

and:
\draw[red,->] (O) -- ($(O)!2cm!90:(M)$) coordinate(Y) node[pos=1.075]{y};


\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,
>=stealth'
]
\coordinate[label=D] (D) at (0,0);
\draw[blue, <-](D) arc[start angle=90, end angle=150, radius=7] coordinate [pos=0.5] (O);

% New CoSy ===============
% center of circle-arc
\coordinate[overlay](M) at ($(D)-(0,7)$);
% x
\draw[red,->] (O) -- ($(O)!2cm!(M)$) coordinate(X) node[pos=1.075]{x};
% y
\draw[red,->] (O) -- ($(O)!2cm!90:(M)$) coordinate(Y) node[pos=1.075]{y};
% z
\draw[red,->] (O) -- ($(O)!2cm!90:(Y)$) coordinate(Z) node[pos=1.075]{z};

\draw pic [draw, angle radius=5mm, "$\cdot$"] {angle =Y--O--Z};
% =====================

\coordinate (P) at ($(O) + (45:2)$); % (45:2) is perpendicular to the x and z axes
\begin{scope}[shift=(P)]
\draw[smooth,variable=\Vt,domain=180:275] plot ({2*cos(\Vt)},{2*sin(\Vt)});
\end{scope}

% Points better at the end
\filldraw[] (O) circle[radius=2pt] node [left] {Origin};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

